# Export variable - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

I have a component called Component1 in which I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Popover from "material-ui-popup-state/HoverPopover";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import {
  usePopupState,
  bindHover,
  bindPopover
} from "material-ui-popup-state/hooks";
import PaletteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Palette";
import Colors from "./Colors";

const DEFAULT_COLOR = "red";
const COLORS = [/*list of colors*/];

const Component1 = ({ classes }) => {
  const popupState = usePopupState({
    variant: "popover",
    popupId: "demoPopover"
  });
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(DEFAULT_COLOR);

  return (
    <div className="box" style={{ backgroundColor: selectedColor }}>
      <Fab variant="extended" {...bindHover(popupState)}>
        <PaletteIcon />
      </Fab>
      <Popover
      >
        <div className="color-palette">
          {COLORS.map((color) => (
            <Colors
              key={color}
              selected={selectedColor === color}
              onClick={setSelectedColor}
              color={color}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component1;
```

This component is imported in Component2 where the code is:

```
import React from "react";
import Component1 from "./Component1";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";

function Component2(props) {
  function handleClick() {
    props.onDelete(props.id);
  }

  return (
    <div className="note" style={{ backgroundColor: "selectedColor" }}>
      <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      <p>{props.content}</p>
      <Fab onClick={handleClick}>
        <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
      </Fab>
      <HoverPopover />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component2;
```

In component2 I need to use the `const selectedColor` for styling purpose for `div` with `class="note"`. However the issue is when I select colors from `COLORS` list the background-color of `div` with `class="note"` is not changing. I tried many options but I don't understand how to do it correctly. Please tell me how to do it right.

Comment: you're not setting the selected color when you click on it. Your onClick() function is wrong. It should set the default color of the selected item, i.e. your state will be set with the selected option

Comment: @Mohit In component1 the onClick() function is present already

Comment: Yes agreed, but where are you setting the selected color, like you never called setSelectedColor(<newColour>)? It'll set the state of component 1

Answer (score 0):

To share the "selectedColor" variable, which is actually a state, you would have to pass it through the props to the child component

Your "Component2" should declare the state "selectedColor", and this state and its function must be passed by the props to your "Component1".

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Comment: Sorry I'm new to React I didn't get how can I use lifting-state-up in my code. Maybe you can show code how to do this.